# fstream.read progress indicator

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, progress

I tried creating a progress indicator for reading a file in C++. The problems I am facing are that

1. `tellg()` and `tellp()` both just return either 24 or -1 while reading even though the file is about 400MB in size EDIT: from the thread, that's reading the file tellg() returns the correct values
2. I am not reading the file using a loop, but with a single `read`-instruction

Code (simplified):

```
fstream file;

void readFile(string filename)
{
    file.open(filename, ios::in | ios::binary);
    file.read((char*) &buffer, buffersize);
}
void readFileWithProgressIndicator(string filename)
{
    size_t filesize = getFileSize(filename)
    thread file_read(readFile, filename);

    for( ; ; )
    {
        cout << file.tellg() << ":" << file.tellp() << endl;
    }
    file_read.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1-Program behaviour seems coherent. It looks like your just read your file with 1 call and I suppose your buffersize is 24. Can you check?

2-Proposal

```
std::atomic<std::streampos> fg;
std::atomic<std::streampos> fp;

void readFile(string filename)
{
    fstream file;
    file.open(filename, ios::in | ios::binary);
    file.read((char*) &buffer, buffersize);
    fg=file.tellg();
    fp=file.tellp();
}
void readFileWithProgressIndicator(string filename)
{
    size_t filesize = getFileSize(filename)
    thread file_read(readFile, filename);

    for( ; ; )
    {
        cout << fg << ":" << fp << endl;
    }
    file_read.join();
}
```

Comment: its actually 1002544... that's what's weird

Comment: In my knowledge, `fstream file;` is not threadsafe, please check that point. That could explain your observed behaviour.

Comment: I edited my question. It is in fact not thread safe. What solutions to this could there be?